# Populating ajax data table with codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

i have a problem regarding populating my data using jquery datatables. I am using a codeigniter framework and already have a response in controller and encoded my data in a json format. I don't know why my table is still empty and already called the ajax to populate my data table. although it returns response with my data when i manually type it in my URL but i cant populate my data table in it.

Here is my view table code code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="tbl_users" style="width: 100%;">
               <!--  <a name='btn_add' id='btn_add' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' onclick="add_deduction_title();"><span class='fa fa-plus'></span> Add Deduction title</a> -->
                <thead class="header-th">
                        <tr>
                                <th class="header-th">Full name</th>
                                <th class="header-th">Email</th>
                                <th class="header-th">IP Address</th>
                                <th class="header-th">Role Group</th>
                                <th class="header-th">Status</th>
                                <th class="header-th">Date Created</th>
                                <th class="header-th">Actions</th>                                                            
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public function get_all_users() {
    $list = $this->user_model->getAllUsers();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($list as $value) {
        $fullname = $value->first_name . " " . $value->middle_name . " " . $value->last_name;

        if($value->active == 0) {
            $active_status = '<p style="color:red;">PENDING</p>';
        }else if($value->active == 1) {
            $active_status = '<p style="color:green;">ACTIVATED</p>';
        }
        
        if($value->group_id == 2) {
            $group_name = 'LGU';
        }else if($value->group_id == 3) {
            $group_name = 'Combase/FO';
        }

        $row = array();  
        $row[] = $fullname;
        $row[] = $value->email;
        $row[] = $value->ip_address;
        $row[] = $group_name;
        $row[] = $active_status;
        $row[] = $value->created_on;
        $row[] = '<button onclick="adminview_profile('."'".$value->id."'".');" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">View Profile</button>';

        $data[] = $row;
    }
    $output = array(   
        "data" => $data,
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

and finally here is my js code to populate the said data table which returns data but doesn't populate my table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var spiner = '<div class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size: 26px"></div>';
    const windowLoc = $(location).attr('pathname');
    let url_global = windowLoc.split("/");
    
    // switch(url_global[2]){        /* live */
    switch(url_global[3]){           /* local */
        case "user-manager" :                           
            load_users_content();   
            break;      
    }
    
    /*user-manager*/    
    function load_users_content() {
        var column_order = [];
        var column_center = [];
        var column_disable_sort = [];

        tbl_users_data = [{name: '', value: ''}];

        tbl_users = $('#tbl_users').DataTable({                 
            responsive: true,
            bProcessing: true,
            bServerSide: true,
            deferRender: true,
            order: column_order,
            columnDefs: [
                    { className: 'text-center', targets: column_center },
                    { orderable: false, targets: column_disable_sort },
            ],
            sServerMethod: 'POST',
            sAjaxSource: base_url+'admin/get_all_users',
            fnServerParams: function(aoData) {
                    $.each(tbl_users_data, function(i, field) {
                            aoData.push({ name: field.name, value: field.value });
                    });
            },
            fnDrawCallback: function() {

            }
        });
    }
    /*user-manager*/

    
});
```

Comment: Just to check: Your table is using `serverSide: true`. Does the JSON conform to the specific structure required by that option? See [this page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) ("Returned Data") for details and also see the examples in that page.

Comment: @andrewjames hi thank you. why is this my data table load sometimes not always

Comment: The answer is: I do not know. To get more help, I think you might need to [edit] the question, and _at least_  add the following information: (1) An example of the JSON sent from the server to the DataTable; (2) Information about any console errors which are displayed in your browser (hit F12 to open the console); (3) info about the versions of jQuery and DataTables you are using; (4) anything else which will help us to recreate the problem (a [mre]).  Otherwise, it may be difficult to really help you. Even with all this extra info, it may still be difficult...